# Mismatch between ~ (user's home dir) and logged in user

Tags: bash, shell, nagios

Nagios is a IT infrastructure monitoring system. I am writing a simple plug-in script for it. A special account, nagios, has been created for it, and the script gets run by Nagios under that account.

For debugging purposes, the script is very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "OK - Running okay" ~ `id`
```

It echoes the value of `~`, i.e. the home directory, and the result of the `id` command.

I log into the nagios account (`su -l nagios`), and test it from the command line:

```
OK - Running okay /home/nagios uid=1005(nagios) gid=1007(nagios) groups=1007(nagios),1008(nagcmd)
```

That is exactly what I expect.

I run it from within the Nagios system, the reported results are:

```
OK - Running okay /home/julian uid=1005(nagios) gid=1007(nagios) groups=1007(nagios),1008(nagcmd)
```

Wait, `/home/julian` is *my* account's home directory; but it is logged into the nagios account. That contradiction makes no sense to me; I obviously don't understand how this is meant to work.

Any suggestions how this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Is your script ran by `sudo` by any chance?

```
rpinson@rpinson:~$ echo ~; id
/home/rpinson
uid=61367(rpinson) gid=100(users) groupes=24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),100(users),119(admin)
rpinson@rpinson:~$ sudo -u toto -s
toto@rpinson:~$ echo ~; id
/home/rpinson
uid=1001(toto) gid=1001(toto) groupes=1001(toto)
```

In some cases (like `sudo -u`), the environment is exported so `$HOME` is not resetted for the user executing the command.

In the case of `sudo`, there are ways of using the user's environment:

```
rpinson@rpinson:~$ sudo -u toto -i
toto@rpinson:~$ echo ~; id
/home/toto
uid=1001(toto) gid=1001(toto) groupes=1001(toto)
```

or

```
rpinson@rpinson:~$ sudo -u toto -H -s
toto@rpinson:/home/rpinson$ echo ~; id
/home/toto
uid=1001(toto) gid=1001(toto) groupes=1001(toto)
```

Comment: That is very interesting. I don't have an answer for you. I assumed that Nagios was running under the user nagios and simply spawning a process, not using sudo, but that's beneath the covers.

Comment: My problem is solved (inspired by this, I just specified an explicit path rather than referencing ~, and my other issues vanished. I've decided to accept this answer as the best.

Comment: Great, glad it answers your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nagios is calling into a remote system so probably you are running the script through ssh julian@remote.

Comment: I am connecting via ssh julian@remote to a server. Nagios is running on the server (hopefully as nagios), and is calling the local script. When it runs the local script, `id` is reporting that it is running as nagios. It is just `~` that reports /home/julian.